# Adjust margins and interline spaces in gb4e

Tags: spacing, linguistics, gb4e

I'm trying to condense the space around examples in gb4e, with the goal of removing unnecessary whitespace around examples in an abstract. Here's what gb4e gives me now:

[image: gb4e default spacing]

What I'd like is for the examples to essentially look like part of the running text, as follows:

[image]

In sum, I'd like to remove the left indent before the top level item numbers, remove the vertical space between examples, and remove the vertical space above and below the `exe` environment.

I think `\vspace` commands might work here, but it would get very tedious to do this every time, and I'd also like to do it the 'right' way.

(I also think `linguex` might be able to do this without too much fuss, but I'm used to using gb4e so I'd prefer to stick with it if there's a way to do this.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{exe}
        \ex Blah \begin{xlist}
            \ex Blah
            \ex Blah
        \end{xlist}
        \ex Blah
        \ex Blah
    \end{exe}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've updated the code slightly. There was one spacing parameter that I left out, which interacted with examples with grammaticality judgements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `gb4e` package isn't really designed to be customizable in this way, but it's not to hard to fix as a one time thing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@subex}[2]{\settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1}\itemindent\z@\labelsep#2%
         \topsep0\p@\itemsep0\p@%
         \parsep\p@\partopsep0\p@%
         \leftmargin\labelwidth%
         \ifnum\the\@xnumdepth=1
         \else\advance\leftmargin#2\relax\fi}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{exe}
        \ex Blah \begin{xlist}
            \ex Blah
            \ex Blah
        \end{xlist}
        \ex Blah
        \ex Blah
    \end{exe}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### Adjusting the left margin alone

If you just want to adjust the left margin, but leave the interline spacing the same then use the following redefinition:

```
\renewcommand{\@subex}[2]{\settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1}\itemindent\z@\labelsep#2%
         \ifnum\the\@xnumdepth=1%
           \topsep 7\p@ plus2\p@ minus3\p@\itemsep3\p@ plus2\p@\else%
           \topsep1.5\p@ plus\p@\itemsep1.5\p@ plus\p@%
           \parsep\p@ plus.5\p@ minus.5\p@%
           \advance\leftmargin#2\relax\fi}
```