# Reduce vertical space before and after gb4e in footnote, align example with footnote text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, linguistics, vertical-spacing, gb4e

This is most definitely a follow-up question to [Not excessively stretch vertical space between elements in gb4e (glossing verse text; issue w/ enumitem)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611534/) and probably related to [Adjust margins and interline spaces in gb4e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431988/).

My question is how to remove or reduce the copious amount of vertical space before and after an example in footnotes to what's normal in a footnote, as well as how to horizontally align the example block with the footnote text.

Note: I'm using `enumitem`, which apparently slightly complicates changing definitions in `gb4e`. The `footmisc` package may also place some obstacles.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[
    bottom,
    hang,
]{footmisc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{gb4e}

% Use Roman numerals in footnotes
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375428/
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}{%
  \setcounter{fnx}{0}%
}{%
  \renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\roman{xnumi}}%
}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@footnotetext}{%
  \@noftnotetrue%
  \renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\arabic{xnumi}}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2]

    \begin{exe}
    \ex Swahili (Bokamba 1985: 45):
        \begin{xlist}
        \ex \gll ki-ti na \textbf{m-guu} wa meza \textbf{u-me-vunjika} \\
                \textsc{cl7}-chair and \textsc{cl3}-leg of table
                \textsc{cl3}-\textsc{prf}-broken \\
            \trans `the chair and the leg of the table are broken'
            
        \ex \gll m-guu wa meza na \textbf{ki-ti} \textbf{ki-me-vunjika} \\
                \textsc{cl3}-leg of table and \textsc{cl7}-chair
                \textsc{cl7}-\textsc{prf}-broken \\
            \trans `the leg of the table and the chair are broken'
        \end{xlist}
    \end{exe}}

\lipsum[3]\footnote{\lipsum[4]}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that worked for me in the end was wrapping the example in a minipage to `\linewidth`. This way, there is no excessive vertical space above the example, and it's indented relative to the footnote's text body. I put `\\` after the minipage to create a little space under the environment, so the example would be slightly set off from the beginning of the next footnote, just as it would be in a block of text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[language=english]{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[
    bottom,
    hang,
]{footmisc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{gb4e}

% Use Roman numerals in footnotes
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375428/
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}{%
  \setcounter{fnx}{0}%
}{%
  \renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\roman{xnumi}}%
}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@footnotetext}{%
  \@noftnotetrue%
  \renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\arabic{xnumi}}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2]

    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{exe}
    \ex Swahili (Bokamba 1985: 45):
        \begin{xlist}
        \ex \gll ki-ti na \textbf{m-guu} wa meza \textbf{u-me-vunjika} \\
                \textsc{cl7}-chair and \textsc{cl3}-leg of table
                \textsc{cl3}-\textsc{prf}-broken \\
            \trans `the chair and the leg of the table are broken'
            
        \ex \gll m-guu wa meza na \textbf{ki-ti} \textbf{ki-me-vunjika} \\
                \textsc{cl3}-leg of table and \textsc{cl7}-chair
                \textsc{cl7}-\textsc{prf}-broken \\
            \trans `the leg of the table and the chair are broken'
        \end{xlist}
    \end{exe}
    \end{minipage}\\
    }

\lipsum[3]\footnote{\lipsum[4]}

\end{document}
```

[image]